# Creating a Topological group from modulo multiplication Group.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

If I were to create a Topology out of the Modulo 3 Multiplication group $\mathbb{Z}_3$, what elements would it consist of and why? So $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \{0,1,2\}$ as a group over modulo 3. What are the elements of this group as a Topology?

Note: I edited out what I thought it would look like and why as it was pointed out that it was confusing, and I can not figure out how to better explain my methodology.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: A finite Hausdorff topological group is always discrete.

Comment: Which makes sense as each neighborhood would be separated, not sure what that would mean though for whether or not the above would be a topological group - and if so, whether or not this kind of construction works in general.

Comment: I'll be honest I had a hard time reading your post. It's not very clear at all what your question even is.

Comment: I am trying to create a Topology on the group $\mathbb{Z_3}$ I would like to know if what I have done is in the right direction for doing so and if I have the right idea in my methodology. If that doesn't make sense, then disregard my efforts above and envision the question as "Is or can $\mathbb{Z_3}$ be a topological group?" If so how, and if not why?

Comment: Every group can be made into a topological group by giving it the discrete or indiscrete (trivial) topology.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Do you know if I am on the right track above? If not or my attempt is not understandable - could you give an example of how to turn the Modulo multiplication 3 group into a topology?

Comment: You are correct when you say the discrete topology turns $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ into a topological group (because every function from a discrete space into another space is continuous, and the product of two discrete spaces is still discrete). You use some unclear terms such as "potential" topology and "I envision this as something like a permutation group" which means very little. The rest of your question is a jumbled mess that I can't parse at all.

Comment: DanielRust . As I said, I don't know if it would be a topology hence "potential", potential = "is it a topology"? To avoid comments concerning semantics of non-mathematical words and those which do not address the question I have removed my calculations and procedure.

Comment: Is there anything my comments didn't cover? I'm happy to flesh out a more complete answer if there's something in particular you wanted to know beyond "what is a topology on this set?"

Comment: I had wanted to know if the elements I listed was indeed a topology on $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \{0,1,2\}$ - is $$\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1, 2\},\{1, 3\},\{2,3 \},\{1, 2,3 \}\}$$? That is a start. But furthermore as $G \times G \rightarrow G$ hence $(g_1,g_2) \mapsto g_1 \cdot g_2$, how does this play in to it? I am a little bit unconfident as I could then just take any group, find the powerset of it and then I have a discreet Topology, I miss the motivation for that (I am looking around though), but again, what does the binary operation $(g_1,g_2) \mapsto g_1 \cdot g_2$?

Comment: "What does the binary operation?" That is not even a complete sentence. "What are the elements of this group as a topology" also doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you're not giving it the discrete topology, and you don't consider the trivial topology (i.e. only the total and the empty set as topology, the coarsest topology that exists).  Then there is an open set with two elements, say $\{a,b\}$.  Clearly, you can order them so that $a+1=b$ ((modulo $3$, of course).

Translating the above by the group action you get that $\{0,1\}, \{1,2 \}, \{2,0\}$ are all open sets, and so this is precisely the discrete topology, after you intersect them in pairs.

Thus, the only possibility is the discrete topology, if your topology is not to be the trivial topology.

You can play this trick on any finite cyclic group, and you'll get that every topology, including the trivial topology, follows from taking the initial topology of an epimorphism

$\phi:C_n\twoheadrightarrow G,$ where $G=C_m$ is discrete cyclic of order $m$ and $m|n,$ or $0$ -that is, $$T=\{\phi^{-1}(U): U \mbox{ open in } G\}.$$  The case of the trivial topology would be to consider the trivial group $\{0\}$.

Thus, the 'atom' open set that generates the whole topology is precisely $Ker\ \phi$, which is $\{0\}$ when $\phi=Id.$

Comment: Thanks Theon. I am guessing that you meant $\{0,1\}, \{1,2 \}, \{2,0\}$? Just making sure I am not missing something. Also the "Supergross" topology you refer to - is it the same as the Indiscrete Topology?

Comment: Yes, of course, 3=0.  I changed it.  The indiscrete topology? I guess we're talking about the same object: the topology which consists of the total set and the empty set, and no other sets.  I think it's called trivial topology, as well.

Comment: Oops!  That's right, it's the coarsest topology there is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a totally different approach would be to consider your elements as rotations of $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ acting on a regular 3-gon i.e. an equilateral triangle?